# Binary file simple read then write not working

Tags: c++, file, binary

Below is the code. For right now, all I want to do is read in a binary file and then write that same binary to make sure I did the reading and the writing correctly [i.e. without changing the file].

I used test.rar (size 333 bytes -- a rar'ed txt file). The output file was 133kb and fails to extract using winrar (after being renamed test.rar). So I must be doing something wrong and cannot find the mistake.

Also, when I let the commented code run, it outputs "This program cannot run in dos" and starts making beeps and boops repeatedly as it iterates through my vector. It's as if using cout with this data is executing a program. If you know what is causing that, it would be nice to know.

```
#include "Dip.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define USAGE "s\n"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 1) 
    {
        cout << USAGE;
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream in(argv[0], ios::binary);
    fstream::streampos beg = in.tellg();
    in.seekg(0, ios::end);
    const fstream::streampos BUFFER_SIZE = in.tellg() - beg;

    vector<char> outputBuffer;

    if(BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        outputBuffer.resize(BUFFER_SIZE);

        in.read(&outputBuffer[0], outputBuffer.size());
        in.close();
        std::ofstream out("output_file", ios::binary);
        out.write(&outputBuffer[0], outputBuffer.size());
        out.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "main::file is empty" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    //for(vector<char>::const_iterator itr = outputBuffer.begin(); itr !=outputBuffer.end(); ++itr)
        //cout << *itr;

    // success!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as the commented section not working, `cout` with binary content can include DOS control characters like `0x07 (BEL)`, which can cause a beep, and various non-printable characters. If you saw any output, some of them might have been "smiley faces", or musical notes, or inverted colors. Printing binary content to the console makes no sense; if you want to view the output, use a hex viewer on the file instead. There are many free applications available; you should be able to find one via google.

Comment: Is "ifstream in(argv[0], ios::binary);" a typo?  You are modifying the program itself.

Comment: HAHAHA! You solved the problem! I meant to use [1] to read in argument 1 on the command prompt! As for comment 1 -- I am not trying to view the hex. I just put that in there as a sad attempt at debugging. My end goal is to suck in the binary so I can encrypt it into a picture!

Comment: Another happy customer.  Glad to help.